# Wierd font change when adding highlightjs to Hugo website using blowdown and Anatole theme

Tags: javascript, css, highlight.js

I am trying to add [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org) to my Hugo website with Anatole theme.

This is how a code chunk looks like before adding highlightjs:

[image]

And this is how it looks like after adding highlight.js:

[image]

This is of course not the way it should look.

To add highlight.js I added the following code to `layouts/partials/head.html`:

```
  <link 
    rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.5.1/styles/default.min.css"
  />
  <script 
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.5.1/highlight.min.js">
  </script>

  <script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.5.1/languages/r.min.js">
  </script>

  <script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.5.1/languages/python.min.js">
  </script>
```

And I added the following code to `layouts/partials/article_footer_js.html`:

```
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Che Martin, you're going to run into a problem asking about theme integrations for Hugo on stack, in that, it's the theme builders code. You would post an issue or request on the theme builders site. Just for future use if you wonder why you don't really get an answer with such theme specific questions as it's not actually a hugo question...

Comment: I understand. I thought of it more like a css/highlight.js question, but I see your point now. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm not very good at css but I found a solution. My solution was to add a file `assets/scss/partials/components/_code.scss` with the following content:

```css
pre code.hljs, 
code.hljs, 
.hljs, 
.hljs-comment,
.hljs-tag,
.hljs-punctuation,
.hljs-tag .hljs-name,
.hljs-tag .hljs-attr,
.hljs-keyword,
.hljs-attribute,
.hljs-selector-tag,
.hljs-meta .hljs-keyword,
.hljs-doctag,
.hljs-name,
.hljs-type,
.hljs-string,
.hljs-number,
.hljs-selector-id,
.hljs-selector-class,
.hljs-quote,
.hljs-template-tag,
.hljs-deletion,
.hljs-title,
.hljs-section,
.hljs-regexp,
.hljs-symbol,
.hljs-variable,
.hljs-template-variable,
.hljs-link,
.hljs-selector-attr,
.hljs-operator,
.hljs-selector-pseudo,
.hljs-literal,
.hljs-built_in,
.hljs-bullet,
.hljs-code,
.hljs-addition,
.hljs-meta,
.hljs-meta .hljs-string,
.hljs-emphasis,
.hljs-strong {
    font-family: monospace, monospace;
}
```

And then adding the following line at the end of `assets/scss/main.scss`:

```css
@import './partials/components/code';
```

With these changes the font family of the highlighted code went back to monospace and the font size is the same for all the code.